# Unable to collect all the shop names from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to parse some names from a webpage. The items available in that webpage doesn't get displayed all at a time, rather, it is necessary to scroll to the bottom to let the webpage release few more items and again few more upon another scrolling and so on until all items are visible. The problem is the items are not located in the body that is why `driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")` this command is not working (IMO). It is located in the left sided area like a sliding container. How can I reach the bottom of that container and parse the names from this webpage? I've written almost all the codes except for controlling the lazy-load. I'm attaching an image to give you an idea what did i try to mean by calling it a sliding container.

The link to that webpage: [Link](https://www.weedsta.com/dispensaries/in/california)

This what I've tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver; import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("replace_the_above_link")

check_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)
    height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;") 
    if height == check_height: 
        break 
    check_height = height

for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".select_list h2 a"))):
    print(item.text)

driver.quit()
```

This is the image of that box which contains item: [Click Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y9zfzpsdao9kup5/Untitled.jpg?dl=0)

Currently my scraper is parsing items which are visible when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Below code should allow you to make XHR requests by scrolling container as much time as possible and then scrape required data:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.weedsta.com/dispensaries/in/california")

entries_count = len(wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "select_list"))))

while True:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("tel").send_keys(Keys.END)
    try:
        wait.until(lambda driver: entries_count < len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("select_list")))
    except:
        break


for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".select_list h2 a"))):
    print(item.text)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your intervention and the script. Plus one for it. Anyways, when I execute your code it produces the same result as I was having in the first place without scrolling. Should I put a hardcoded delay anywhere within the while loop? Thanks again for your answer sir.

Comment: Hmm.. This is weird... Did you use it exactly as it appears in my answer or some modifications made?

Comment: No sir, no modification is made. I hardly dare to do so. I've executed it exactly how it is.

Comment: Tried it one more time and still works perfectly... Can you share chromedriver, Chrome and selenium versions?

Comment: Trying to find out the versions. Will be back soon. Thanks sir. Btw, voluntarily i was trying to make it work `for i in range(len(entries_count)):entries_count.send_keys(Keys.END)` but throws an error `object of type 'int' has no len()`.

Comment: These are the version info: `Google Chrome:  Version 62.0.3202.89(Official Build)(32-bit)
selenium version: 3.7.0
Chromedriver version: 2.33` Btw, you might have noticed that there are above 9000 results in that webpage.

Comment: Versions seem to be OK. Not outdated... Yeah, I stopped my script after ~5200 results loaded... :) Still have no idea why `send_keys()` doesn't work for you

Comment: No no that's okay. I just meant did you notice the highest number cause sometimes if i didn't make myself clear then it is hard to answer.

Comment: If i go like this it works. When I run the script available in this link, it fetches me 380 results. That means, in each scroll it reveals 18/20 names. Is it possible to do the same without this hardcoded range what i applied here https://www.dropbox.com/s/nan8ieikawciu8f/hardcoded_range.txt?dl=0